# Perguntas sobre a história de uma linguagem, plataforma ou ambiente são válidas?

Tags: suporte, tags

Numa pergunta que nem lembro qual era eu comentei algo que também não lembro e ganhei uma "resposta" (comentários) do @GuilhermeNascimento falando sobre a história e evolução da web, achei interessante e muito relevante porém acredito que não esteja dentro do escopo do site perguntas como essa (já que não encontrei uma tag para isso)

Mas para ter certeza, Perguntas sobre a história de uma linguagem, plataforma ou ambiente são válidas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu já vi que tem uma predisposição para fazer perguntas amplas. Essa pergunta aqui está falando de muitas coisas, de muitas possibilidades.

Pode fazer, mas precisa ser útil, ter algum propósito, ser respondível, não ter os problemas de sempre.

A *tag* não tem porque seria meio sem propósito, mas se fizer de um jeito que faça sentido tudo bem.

Isto conta? [O que significa # no nome de algumas linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106786/101).

Tem coisas assim que não são bem história, mas tem raízes históricas: [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101).

Isso é história? [Origem da orientação a objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54310/101)

Acho que isto é, não? [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101).

Tem *tags* que podem encaixar como [design-de-linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-de-linguagem) ou [característica-linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-linguagem). Não que eu esteja sugerindo. E talvez poderia ter alguma outra *tag*, mas dá medo, o pessoal usa errado certas *tags*, como seria uma [linguagem-de-programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linguagem-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) muito abusada.

Bem feita eu acho válido.